# Redirecting to different view after an AJAX call Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to activate my user by doing an AJAX call. I have this jQuery code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).one('click','.continue-button',function(){

        $.ajaxSetup({

            headers: {

                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

            }

        });

        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({

            url: '/activate',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id : id},
            success: function(res){

            }

        });

    });

});
```

It takes the `data-id` attribute of my button, which is the user's id and sends an AJAX call. This is how my route looks like:

```
Route::post('/activate','ActiveController@activate');
```

My function:

```
public function activate(Request $request)
    {

        $id = $request->input('id');

        User::where('id',$id)->update([

            'active' => '1'

        ]);

        return redirect('/loadDashboard');

    }
```

It activates the user and then redirects to '/loadDashboard' route. This is how the route looks like:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{

    Route::get('/loadDashboard','ActiveController@loadDashboard');  

});
```

And finally my `loadDashboard` function:

```
public function loadDashboard()
    {

        return view('dashboard')->with('title','Dashboard');

    }
```

I want to redirect the user to my `dashboard` view in aforementioned function, but it seems to return the view to my AJAX call. I can see the view in Inspect->Network. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of this

`return redirect('/loadDashboard');`

put this

`return response()->json(['url'=>url('/loadDashboard')]);`

and in your `ajax success` function put this:

```
 success: function(res){
   window.location=res.url;
 }
```